# Was this Question Primarily Opinion Based? In my opinion it was, review audit disagrees

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Was this Question Primarily Opinion Based?

In my opinion it was, however the review audit does not agree with this.

I voted to Leave Closed.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/10989406

What are your thoughts?

Comment: The question is borderline and therefore the audit is invalid. Audits should be clear, not ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'd seen the question originally, I'd have voted to close.

If I'd seen the question on the reopen queue, I'd have voted to leave closed, especially if it had been indicated that it was in the reopen queue due to an edit on a closed/hold question, and the edit was obviously to put that "Edit:" into it, which doesn't affect any possible Close reason.

Like you, that would have been done on the basis of various indicators which normally lead to a reason for closing.

However, with Pekka's answer, I've looked more closely (I have no domain knowledge) and have decided I would still have taken the same actions.

"Better" is subjective, even in a fairly tight description. Without the scope of "better" in the question it is Too Broad. I'd still have voted to leave it closed.

Without any indication of where memory/CPU/user-experience/somethingelse is the determinant for "better", I can still see nothing but a question which cannot be answered concretely, and which answer only directly helps the oner person with that particular app.

Looking outside the question, are the answers (assuming correct) useful more broadly for future searchers? No. There is little to aid them in determining what is "better" in their specific situation.

Boss: Why did you do that?
Searcher: SO told me it was better.
Boss: Well, it wasn't. The client is very upset. Why did you think SO knew what was important to the client?

I've now voted to Close as Too Broad. Primarily Opinion as a reason would not be the end of the world.

Comment: Rats, that was supposed to be a comment on Pekka's answer. Have to make it look a bit better now :-)

Answer (score 1):

On a quick glance (and with little knowledge in the tag), I'd probably have voted to reopen personally.

The question is *extremely* specific in what it wants to know, the pros and cons the OP is already aware of, etc.

It's far from being a typical lazy "what is the best way to do xyz" question.

Comment: Fair point, just looking for other peoples opinions on the matter, with something that starts with "which is better..."  I instantly feel it is an opinion when both options _work_.

Comment: Until they outline the scope for determining "better" I don't think it's a particularly good question, and there's too much scope for people to determine their own criteria for "better" (in some cases based on totally subjective opinions).