# Why was this reopen audit question NOT considered Primarily opinion based?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I [failed this audit today](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/15798638) on my Reopen review queue.

Was this question primarily opinion based?

In my opinion it was, however the audit does not agree with this.

I voted to Leave Closed. I [read the question thoroughly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857135/why-is-async-considered-better-performing-than-multithreading), looked at the comments and the answers on the question and considered the history of the SO community that questions that are subjective, like 'Why' questions, are to be closed.  After failing the audit, I went to the question directly and found that it was still open. I was actually surprised that it wasn't already closed even after being asked weeks ago, what with the rush-to-close crowd that is evident. My guess is the system took an open question and used it as the metric for 'should be open' when in this case, this question as evaded the mightly close hammer of Mjolnir.

Don't get me wrong, the asker did a really good job of constructing a clear question that is definitely a programming question and I would normally like to see this type of question allowed, mainly because the audience on this site is the exact right group to provide the background and detail needed here.

[Similiar meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315243/was-this-question-primarily-opinion-based-in-my-opinion-it-was-review-audit-di) but different reason for close determination.  Found these meta questions that discuss the same problems with [failed audits on a primarily opinion based question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266964/failed-audit-reason-primarily-opinion-based-based) where the audit was likely incorrect (and that [the moderators answer is reassuring](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267077/135078) now does not help with the frustration of failing an audit at the time) vs this other meta question where the question was [subtly different yet was considered NOT opinion-based](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320126/why-is-this-question-considered-as-primarily-opinion-based)

Nonetheless, the consensus is these are opinion-based and should be closed unless they have historical significance, so how did this get into the audit as 'should be reopened'?

[Edit]
My question can be separated into multiple portions,
**1)** why did I fail the audit (I understand, I disagreed with the audit)
**2)** **why is this question not considered primarily opinion-based**
**3)** why is this question considered a valid question for an audit (I understand, there is a question-selection algorithm)

The first part is not an issue for me as I can say I understand why I failed the audit, the open question was considered as 'properly open' due to several factors. The second part may be less controversial but I'd suggest that questions where there is no votes to close can not always be relied upon to be considered 'properly open'. The third part is more what is at issue.  Why is the question not already closed?  I'll add another aspect, maybe this shows the needs for a feature request.  Just because a question has not been closed it shouldn't automatically be considered for use in an audit, specifically for 'reopen question closed with reason of primarily opinion-based' reviews.  To reduce the incidents of this happening, the system can select questions that have had at least 1 close vote (reason: opinion-based) and was not closed.  This is a low bar to get over and at least guarantees that a minimum of 1 voter considered it as potentially opinion-based.

Comment: it was picked as an audit automagically due to it's score and lack of downvotes/closevotes. Whether or not it actually is primarily opinion based is of course another thing entirely. I don't think it is primarily opinion based.

Comment: Kind of the same thing as [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346622/is-there-a-flaw-in-audits-or-am-i-missing-the-point)

Comment: For those who voted to close this or downvoted, please realize that the question in question has been closed and now has reopen votes, which is the heart of my feature request. Please reopen this for further discussion.